# MYSQL and Paypal

Tags: mysql, paypal, integration

I am trying to figure out a way to configure paypal and mysql. For example: After a user has purchased something, I want paypal to verify that the payment has gone through and it will update my database in phpmyadmin and it will output the necessary information (transaction id, how much etc.).

How would I be able to do the above? Can anyone provide links to tutorials and helpful steps. Thanks!

Also: I've tried looking through the paypal dev section, no luck. I've searched through multiple topics and I have had no luck into what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You want to utilize PayPayl's [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) system.

IPN can be setup to make callbacks to your system. The callbacks include all of the information that you need, including the transaction ID and the status.

PayPal will not integrate with your database directly. You need a web server and some code in between PayPal and your database.

They provide sample code in various languages, including PHP.

Be sure to use their sandbox facility for testing. You'll need to apply for a [sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Comment: i don't believe this answer will do. he was looking for you to actually do his work for him

Comment: Funny! OP wanted a link, so I provided a link and an overview. :)

Comment: +1 this exactly the type of answer the OP should get to such a broad question